# Using a line from a text file as a parameter for an API call with Python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am working on a program that reads a line from a text file then inserts the line into a string

```
import requests
import json

f = open(r"\source\Requests_search_IMDB.txt", "r")
line=f.readlines(1)

url = "https://movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com/"

#this needs to pull from the text file
querystring = {"s":"{line}","page":"1","r":"json"}
headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-key': "HOST_KEY",
    'x-rapidapi-host': "movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

I cant seem to get the line to be inserted into the querystring correctly. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: where are you using `querystring ` variable ??

Comment: It looks like in "params = lines" the "lines" variable is never defined.

Comment: ah sorry, it was incorrect I just edited the post above. Thanks!

Comment: In your querystring `"s":"{line}"` should be `"s":f"{line}"` or just `"s":line`

Comment: when trying  ```"s":f"{line}"``` or just ```"s":line``` it is unable to find the movie.